# Redirect requests to different domains bases on request url in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to redirect requests to 2 different servers(Server-A and Server-B) based on the request received on original apache server.

Server-A is also another apache server and Server-B is weblogic server. I am using weblogic proxy plugin directive to redirect requests for Server-B. So only requests which has context as /console or /mywlsapp should be redirected to weblogic server. All other requests should be redirected to Server-A.

I tried to exclude WLS contexts using ReWrite Cond. But it didn't worked.

This is my rewrite rules. Can you help me with this?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/console/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywlsapp/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycustomapp\.mycompany\.com:7090 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://mycustomapp\.mycompany\.com:7090
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://Server-A.mycompany.com/$1 [P]

<Location /console>
WLSRequest On
SetHandler weblogic-handler
WebLogicHost Server-B
WebLogicPort 7110
</Location>

<Location /mywlsapp>
SetHandler weblogic-handler
WebLogicHost Server-B
WebLogicPort 7112
</Location>
```

Comment: "I tried to exclude WLS contexts using ReWrite Cond. But it didn't worked." - so that means that http://example.com/console is also redirected to Server A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you might want is this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/console/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywlsapp/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycustomapp\.mycompany\.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^7090$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://Server-A.mycompany.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should 301 redirect

```
http://mycustomapp.mycompany.com:7090/foo
```

to

```
http://Server-A.mycompany.com/foo
```

However, all of the above conditions must be fulfilled for this redirect to happen, in clear English:

1. URI may not begin with `/console/` or `/mywlsapp/` **AND**
2. Host has to be exactly `mycustomapp.mycompany.com` **AND**
3. Port has to be exactly `7090`

Please note that e.g. `http://mycustomapp.mycompany.com:7090/console` will not be redirected, but `http://mycustomapp.mycompany.com:7090/console/` will.